# back button press for view in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` with 2 fragments A and B. Fragment A opens Fragment B.

Fragment B has 4 (a,b,c,d) views in it and each view loads corresponding xml. When I am in 3 of my views a,b,c
and press back button, I go to Fragment A which is fine. But when I am in the view 'd' and press back button, I must go to view 'c'
and not Fragment A. How can I achieve this scenario?

My MainActivity has `onBackPressed()` method and it looks like this-

```
for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {

            if (frag != null && frag.isVisible()) {

                FragmentManager childFm = frag.getChildFragmentManager();

                if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

                    childFm.popBackStack();
                    return;
                    }
                }
        }

        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();

            finish();
        }
```

Comment: Is a,b,c and d also fragment instance ?

Comment: They are basically linear layout views inflated with their containers as visible and main container GONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to achieve this you have to listen back press event in the fragment.

First, create an Interface for back press callback.

```
public interface BackPressListener {
    void onBackPressed();
}
```

Second, Configure your activity like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BackPressListener backPressListener;

    public void setBackPressListener(BackPressListener backPressListener) {
        this.backPressListener = backPressListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressListener != null)
            backPressListener.onBackPressed();
        else super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Third, listen to back press event from fragment.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements BackPressListener {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity) context).setBackPressListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle your back press event here
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(getActivity() instanceof  MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setBackPressListener(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me error cyclic inheritance invloving MyFragment

Comment: how it is a cyclic inheritance. I think you have done something wrong. Post your error message

Comment: Yeah my mistake... I solved it but I am not sure in onBackPressed() what I must do to goto view C

Comment: Check visibility of your A,B,C,D views. you have to change visibility if D is visible. else you have to call popBackStack()

Comment: Upvote it and mark it as correct answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to View-D, make a boolean variable true and on backbutton press, check if that boolean is true then show the view-C.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isViewD_Visible) {
        // show View-C
        isViewD_Visible = false;
    }else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **doing something wrong** here, You might face similar issue on smaller devices where your requirement is to **go to b if you press back on c**

You should **consider using fragments instead of LinearLayouts**, You can add **child fragments** inside a fragment using `getChildFragmentManager()`. While adding child fragment you can mention addToBackStack as well. Then Android system will handle back itself.

e.g.

```
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
            .addToBackStack(tag)
            .commit()
```